# Play a PCM/Opus stream on a website with nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, discord.js, pcm

I want to play a pcmstream or opusstream on a website using `http` and `discord.js`.

I created a webserver with nodejs:

```
http.createServer((request, response) => {

 response.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'audio/wav',
  'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
 });

}).listen(19);
```

And created a PCMStream/OpusStream of a users voice:

```
connection.on("speaking", (user, speaking) => {

 if (speaking) {

  var PCMStream = receiver.createPCMStream(user);
  var OpusStream = receiver.createOpusStream(user);

 }

})
```

**How can I play one of these streams on the webserver I created before?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a permanent voice stream for a website with discordjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231762/how-to-create-a-permanent-voice-stream-for-a-website-with-discordjs)

Comment: @jerseyetr In the other post, I wanted to play sound via streaming .wav files and with an extern webserver. Here I'm trying to directly create the webserver in the same file where the stream is.

Comment: Make sure your usage of the user's voice data complies with the [Discord Developer Terms of Service](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/legal) (specifically provisions 2.4 and 2.5).